# sysnetwk.exe adware virus removal Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, proxy, virus, malware

`sysnetwk.exe` keeps changing my proxy and browser settings which results in manually resetting proxy settings and dealing with bunch of adware popup etc.

I have tried many methods and malware removers which include:

- Removed suspicious programs from Add/Remove programs list
- Removed unnecessary extensions from browsers
- Malware removal tools I tried:

  - HitmanPro
  - MalwareBytes Adware Cleaner
  - Bitdefender Adware Remover Tool
  - SpyHunter 4
  - MalwareBytes
  - Zemana AntiMalware
  - Microsoft Essentials
  - Deleting Temp files
  - Deleting `sysnetwk.exe`, but it keeps coming back
  - Remove/Reset all browsers

I tried all these within ***safe mode*** too.

Every time I manually reset proxy settings, many CMD windows flash up and triggers the proxy to change.

Proxy is always changed to `http=127.0.0.1:8080;https=127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: @Steven Yep, Im aware of that. However, I created a new post since I have tried all answers available on that post

Comment: If all those methods failed it's time to reinstall Windows.  It basically means you have a rootkit infection